# How to solve a cryptarithm?

Tags: puzzle, cryptarithm

Given multiplication is
$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
  &   &   & P & E & N \\
  &   &   & I & N & K \\\hline
  &   & L & K & P & R \\
  & I & R & T & N &   \\
E & A & K & N &   &   \\\hline
L & E & T & T & E & R
\end{array}$$

how to find the values of the letters?

Comment: If you get stuck: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/applet/metic/metic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from N*N ends in N, so N must be 5 or 6 (can't be 0 or 1 from the second line in the sum).  Then I*N ends in N (and I !=1) says N is 5 and I is odd.  Then K is even and R is 0.  Continue

Comment: @Whoever it was that posted a comment: your math didn't render, and was breaking the comment display, so I removed it. Please try to re-post it correctly.

Comment: Can we be sure that the second block represents:
$
\begin{array}{llllll}  
 &&K &(P & E & N) \\  
 &N &(P & E & N)& \\  
 I &(P & E & N)&& \\  
\end{array} 
$
and not:
$
\begin{array}{llllll}  
 &&N &(I & N & K) \\  
 &E &(I & N & K)& \\  
 P &(I & N & K)&& \\  
\end{array} 
$

Comment: It has in all cryptarithms I have ever solved and matches the way I was taught to do multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Rules:

1) If $ A+B=A$ then $B= 0$ or  $9$.

Answer (score -2):

### 6 1 5 * 354

```
 2 4 6 0
```

3 0 7 5

### 1 8 4 5

2 1 7 7 1 0

Comment: -1. The OP ask for the way of find the values, no the answer.

Comment: Please state it in a way that's easier to understand. Even saying that $615 \times 354 = \ldots$ is much better than what you have.

Comment: I * N = N and N * N = N implies N=5; ans I is odd ,it may be {1, 3 7,9} since N is 5. and k * N (5) = R ;imples R is 0 ;

Comment: observe column  KTN T ==> K+N=10 ; it cannot be 5+5.. if K cannot greater than 5 since adding 6 or greater will result in value greater than 10 and condition K+T+N= T fails. therefore K must be less than ; also observe 1st partial product P * K = K (+L ->carry) implies K is even and P is 6. so K can be now either 2 or 4. since 0 6 are already consumed. Now observe  N(5)+P= E +(10). We know P=6; therefore E= 1; Now you know P E N K R values, do multiplication and you will get values in first partial product. which gives L=2 and from column L+R+K=T ==> T=L+5;